# iOS map in xamarin forms, does it work offline?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am just curious if the xamarin forms map that u use for ios works when you have no internet? and if not, can you possibly download a certain area and include it in the app when they download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the standard Apple map will not work offline.  There may some caching going on under the covers, but you have no control over it.  If you want an offline maps solution you would need to investigate a third party control that allows explicit caching and write a custom renderer for it.

Comment: ok, do you have any useable links to third party controls that i could use?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two possible options for your request. [Osmsharp](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46803/using-xamarin-forms-maps-for-offline-use) and [nutiteqmapssdk and iOS offline](http://nutiteqmapssdk%20&%20iOS%20offline%20app)